# Create a PHP Poll with just one vote per IP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an Ajax Poll for my website users, but in our case a user can vote an unlimited number of times after he refreshes the page, and the results are being recorded.

I would like to let users vote just one time from their IP and after they have voted, at page refresh just to show them the results.

Here is the code

The HTML Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0)
  {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
  }
if ($vote == 1)
  {
  $no = $no + 1;
  }

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to let users vote just one time from their IP and after they have voted, at page refresh just to show them the results.

Comment: Do you have a database?

Comment: no, the results are stored in a .txt file: 8||3 (8 times yes, and 3 times no)

Comment: I would also highly recommend using a database for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user's IP address like so:

```
$insertvote = $yes . "||" . $no . "||" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

However, without a database, it is bound to become unmanageable as the file gets bigger and you have to scan through the file in order to check if an IP already exists. You could limit votes by session, but then again, that won't be completely fool proof either (nor is limiting votes by IP, by the way).

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['voted'])){
    die('You have already voted.');
}

$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0){
    $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1){
    $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
$write = fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);

if($write !== false){
    $_SESSION['voted'] = true;
}
?>
<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```